# Python doesn't let me modify a list passed as an argument

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to work through a code signals challenge. Basically, I am given a list of integers.  I am to sort the integers in an ascending order without changing the indexes of -1.  So only the positive integers are sorted while the -1s stay where they are.  To solve this, I decided to create a separate, sorted list of all the positive integers.  Then, while iterating through the list, I replace each positive integer from the list passed as an argument with the new sorted list I've made.

Here is my code:

```
def sortByHeight(a):
    
    sorted_list = sorted([i for i in a if i > 0])
    count = 0
    
    for i in range(0, len(a)-1):
        if a[i] > 0:
            a[i] == sorted_list[count]
            count += 1
    
    return a
```

But when I return a, it seems as though the given list is completely unmodified.  Here are some test cases:

```
Input: a: [-1, 150, 190, 170, -1, -1, 160, 180]
Output: [-1, 150, 190, 170, -1, -1, 160, 180]
Expected Output: [-1, 150, 160, 170, -1, -1, 180, 190]
```

```
Input: a: [2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1]
Output:[2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1]
Expected Output:[1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 2]
```

While I appreciate all help, I am not looking for a quick fix or a long-winded explanation on using a different approach.  I know that my approach is good and to help me learn, I would just like an explanation on what tweaks I need to make to this existing code.

Comment: use `print()` inside code to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables. OR learn how to use debuger.

Comment: you have to use `=` instead of `==` in line `a[i] = sorted_list[count]`

Comment: `a[i] == sorted_list[count]` is a comparison, not an assignment

Comment: BTW: you have to use `range(0, len(a))` without `-1` - or shorter `range(len(a))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've compiled the comments on your OP into one code snippet:

```py
def sortByHeight(a):

  sorted_list = sorted([i for i in a if i > 0])
  count = 0

  for i in range(0, len(a)):
    if a[i] > 0:
      a[i] = sorted_list[count]
      count += 1

  return a
```

- There was a comparison operator (`==`) rather than an assignment
  operator (`=`) on line 8

> you have to use = instead of == in line a[i] = sorted_list[count]
>
> – furas

- `len(a) - 1` was the incorrect number, and should have been `len(a)`
  instead (line 6)

> BTW: you have to use range(0, len(a)) without -1 - or shorter range(len(a))
>
> – furas

Comment: OK. I don't know why you use `str()` at the end. It could be more useful to keep it as list

Comment: Thanx man. Do I feel like a dummy lol.  I gave you an upvote and accepted your answer.  If you think that this was a well asked question, could you give me an upvote as well?

Answer (score 0):

You got a proper answer already, let me just show another way to write the same approach which I think is not only nicer but also might've avoided those two bugs (not using indexed looping avoids getting the index limit wrong, and if you did a comparison here, you'd see booleans instead of no changes).

```
>>> it = iter(sorted(x for x in a if x > 0))
>>> [next(it) if x > 0 else x for x in a]
[-1, 150, 160, 170, -1, -1, 180, 190]
```

Or with a `for`-loop, but still using an iterator and using `enumerate` (also avoids the possibility of that index/limit bug):

```
it = iter(sorted(x for x in a if x > 0))
for i, x in enumerate(a):
    if x > 0:
        a[i] = next(it)
```